# Using while loops for inputs for coding python

Tags: while-loop

I have an assignment due and im stuck the objective is to get 5 user inputs and find the mean. PLS HELP lol/

Answer (score 0):

I regret the times i cheated even though I didn't get caught

```
numbers = 0
count = 0
while count < 5:
    number = int(input("input number: "))
    numbers = number + numbers
    count = count + 1
print(numbers)
avg = numbers/5
print(avg)
```